# Use the HTML5 web MIDI API

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, web-audio-api, web-midi

I'm trying to make a simple synth web-app using the web audio API and I want to use it with my MIDI keyboard through the web MIDI API, so I tried these instructions both on Chrome and Chrome Canary but always I get the "navigator.getMIDIAccess is not a function" error, the version is 40 for Chrome and 42 for Chrome Canary, both on Mac OS X (10.10.2) and the experimental flag has been enabled.
The code for now is very simple (this is a test):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
try{
    //navigator.getMIDIAccess = ( navigator.getMIDIAccess || navigator.webkitGetMIDIAccess || navigator.mozGetMIDIAccess || navigator.msGetMIDIAccess);
    navigator.getMIDIAccess(_event_success, function(){
        alert("ERROR");
    });
}catch(ex){
    console.log(ex);
    alert("NOT SUPPORTED");
}

function _event_success(){
    console.log("OK");
}
</script>
```

Where is the error?
If may be helpful I'm using a M-AUDIO Keystation88 keyboard on USB.
Is Chrome the only one that suport this feature?

Answer (score 2):

The api call is "requestMIDIAccess".  (It is not prefixed.)

Comment: I've done a attempt using the prefixes with no success so after that I've commented the line. So the right form is "navigator. requestMIDIAccess(onSuccess, onError);"?

Comment: (Sorry for delay) - sort of - there is an options object that you can pass in to ask for system exclusive support.  For your case, you can pass in an empty object (or null) - so navigator.requestMIDIAccess(null, onSuccess, onError).

Comment: Thanks very much for help, I've done a simple example and it works fine, here the code if it may be helpful for some one else with this problem: https://gist.github.com/RyanJ93/8c0d78323ab13787ea51